# Problems trying to open a word document for editing in Windows store application

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, openxml-sdk

I'm tyring to use Microsoft Open XML SDK 2.0 within a Windows 8 store application to edit an existing MS word document.

So, I create a blank windows store application. I then use NuGet to install DocumentFormat.OpenXml. This seems to work OK but when I compile the application I get the following error:

```
While creating .pri files for portable libraries, sub-task 'GenerateProjectPriFile' failed while processing library 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml'.
```

Any ideas how to use the Open XML libraries within a windows 8 store application and also how to open word documents from within the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research it seems the Open XML can't be used with Windows store apps